# inotify_event returns wd -1

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I am initializing `INOTIFY` by using `inotify_init()` and I call `read` with no mask flags. When I want to use the watch descriptor `wd` I can see that it is returned with value -1. Reading the man page I can see that this value is set only when the even queue overflowed, BUT only if the call to read has the mas bit IN_Q_OVERFLOW set so It is not my case.

What the reason could be to have a wd set to -1? On top of that I don't have -1 returned by read so this means NO ERROR during this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you misread the manual, [inotify_init(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_init.2.html) clearly says:

> On success, these system calls return a new file descriptor.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

So look in errono, to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You are totally right. I didn't read the man pages. When they mentioned the 'mask' I thought it was a bit flag to be set as read argument, not the one to be bit-wised from the 'mask' argument of notify_event.